# Moving tabs doesn't work anymore since jre1.8.0_20 version update

Tags: java, tabs, javafx

I have a problem : moving a tab of a tabpane from the index 0 to 1 isn't working anymore.

I updated recently the new version of java (8u20). Since then, the "moving tab" feature of my program doesn't work anymore.

Here's my code :

```
    final TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

    final Tab tabOne = new Tab("hello");
    Label label1 = new Label("hello");
    tabOne.setContent(label1);
    tabOne.getContent().setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            tabPane.getTabs().remove(tabOne);
            tabPane.getTabs().add(1, tabOne);
            tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(1);
        }
    });

    Tab tabTwo = new Tab("byebye");
    tabPane.getTabs().add(tabOne);
    tabPane.getTabs().add(tabTwo);
```

As you can see, the code is quite simple : I have two tabs, and I just move the first tab from index 0 to index 1 when a click occurs on its content.
This code works with jre8, but doesn't with jre1.8.0_20 (the tabs disappear ...).

Does someone have an idea of why is this happening ?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably this bug:

https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38490

...which is fixed in the latest 8u40 early access build.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about the new version. Of course, it fixed the problem. I'll know it for the next time.